# Passport js not loggin out user

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to log out the user that has logged in with passport js in my node app. The problem is it doesn't seem to be logging out and I still get users's info when I retrieve their information using req.user. Here's my logout code:

```
app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
    req.logout((err) => {
        if(err) {console.log("error: " + err)}
        req.session.destroy(function (err) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
        });
    });
});
```

And here's how I try to check if the user is still logged in after calling log out function:

```
app.get("/isLogin", function(req, res) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        console.log("it is logged in");
        res.status(200).json(req.user);
    }
    else {
        console.log("it is not logged in");
        res.status(200).json({message: "user not logged in"});
    }
});
```

Also here are my Axios functions for calling logout and isLogin (I'm not sure if I should send credentials when calling logout):

```
 const logOut = () => {
    Axios({
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4000/logout"
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log("logo out");
    })
  }

const isLoggedIn = () => {
    Axios({
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4000/isLogin"
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log("login res: " + res.data);
    })
  }
```

Would appreciate any clues on why logout doesn't work here.